# TYPO3 - add javascript code into content element - I don't know whether it is posible

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

In TYPO3, I want to add some javascript code into content element in a page but I don't know whether it is possible or not.

For example :
[image]

I think this might be solved with typoscript. 
Is there any method available in typoscript for including javascript code into content element?

Also, what is 'page.jsInline' in typoscript??

I got the following code during searching,

```
page.jsInline {
    4711 = TEXT
    4711.dataWrap (
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                            appId: '',
                            status: true,
                            cookie: true,
                            xfbml: true
                    });
            };
            (function() {
                    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                    e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
    )
}
```

I think this might help me.... but what is meant by this number '4711'??

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer heavily depends on what will be in that content element (CE).

If it is a **your custom plugin**, you can do from your plugin's template via [f:uri.resource](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ResourceViewHelper.html) or even better by [v:asset.script](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Asset/ScriptViewHelper.html) (you'll need EXT:vhs for that).

If you want to add your JS to **existing CE**, like "Text", "Image", "Text with Image", etc. and not to all, but to some specified, I don't know an out-of-the-box way to do this. But you can [create a container, which is built only from one grid element](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/grid.html) for your desired CE via EXT:fluidcontent. And put your JS inclusions into container's template.
So, as result you first put your container on a page, and then you put desired CE into container.
I recommend reading [complete manual](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/introduction.html) of Flux-family extensions to get the idea, what you are doing :)

As for `page.jsInline` I recommend to check [TS Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#jsinline) for that. In a nutshell: there are possibilities to add your CSS/JS **globally** for all pages (or not for all, if you use [conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id59)) via different options, which you can find in a TS Refrence (I recommend using `includeJS`). As you can see from a reference, all the CSS/JS inclusion options are arrays, and numbers like *4711* are simply indexes in this array. Usually developers of extensions trying to use some *unique* numbers to avoid overlapping with TYPO3 integrators. So, *4711* is just some random number.

As [@pgampe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234469/pgampe) pointed out: definitions with lower indexes in these arrays are included *before* those with higher indexes.

Comment: Hi Viktor, thank you for the answer...am new to this...so I cant understand the answer completely...
I have a js code and I want to insert this into a particular CE, is it possible to do this with 'page.jsInline' ?

Comment: @JackyCoogan Yes, you can put it in `page.jsInline`, but this will make your code to appear on any page.

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi the numbers are sorted before the page is generated. Therefore the numbers do matter and lower numbers come before higher numbers even if they are defined the opposite way inside TS.

Comment: @pgampe, thank you for pointing this out. From my old experience numbers didn't matter. Seems, this was changed in some TYPO3 version. I'll update my answer.